# append element doesn't trigger event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I would like to add the new input box and 'remove' link after clicking 'More'. Also the input box can be removed by clicking 'remove'.

However, the input box doesn't removed after clicking remove link.

Is there anyone can help em? Many thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

           $('#link').click(function(){
               $('#newField').append('<input type="textbox"><a href="#" id="removeField">Remove</a><br/>');
               });
               $('#removeField').click(function(){
               $("#newField").remove();
           });
        });
    </script>

    <a href="#" id="link" title="Add field by clicking">More</a>
    <div id="newField">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element 'removeField' is not available on DOM when you try to bind the click event. try to bind the event using 'on' http://api.jquery.com/on/ or http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

I think this will accomplish what you wanted to do:

```
<a href="#" id="link" title="Add field by clicking">More</a>
<div id="newField"></div>​

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link').on('click',function() {
    $('#newField').append('<input type="textbox"><a href="#" class="removeField">Remove</a><br/>');
});
$('#newField').on('click','.removeField',function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.prev().remove();
    $this.next().remove();
    $this.remove();
});​
</script>
```

You should really use the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)-function in jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

when you add the field, you don't add an ID to it so you cannot remove it. Try this:

```
$('#newField').append('<input type="textbox" id="monNewField"><a href="#" id="removeField">Remove</a><br/>');
```

But I'd do something like this if I were you, so you can add and remove as many fields as you like:

```
$('#newField').append('<div class="row"><input type="textbox"><a href="#" class="removeField">Remove</a></div>');
```

then:

```
$('.removeField').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```